# 'There are no commands defined in the "baum" namespace' error when using "baum" for implementing Nested Set

Tags: php, laravel

For implement of a **Nested Set** for my news category I want to use **[Baum](https://github.com/etrepat/baum)** package.

After installing this Package via Composer and add **BaumServiceProvider** to **config/app.php** providers, I try to install a new Model named **Category** via Below command:

```
php artisan baum:install MODEL
```

But I faced to the following error :

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
There are no commands defined in the "baum" namespace.
```

Of course I ran `php artisan` command and But there were no command named **Baum** on generated commands list.

What should I do?

Comment: I have the same problem...

Answer (score 3):

First you have to add the code below in config/app.php:

```
Baum\Providers\BaumServiceProvider::class
```

If the problem still persists configuration files may be cached. Just call:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you added

```
 Baum\Providers\BaumServiceProvider::class
```

To the providers array in the app.php file located in config/app.php

Comment: Yes , I was added this line to providers Array.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I know that I have added something into Laravel's core files, and it's not working from the command line, I typically just run

```
php artisan optimize
```

to regenerate all of the classes, and it will typically work.  Running this command is something that I find myself doing fairly often.

Answer (score 0):

In AppServiceProvider.php (app\Providers) you can modify register function:

```
 public function register()
 {
     $this->app->register(\Baum\Providers\BaumServiceProvider::class);
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

Not sure why 5.2 have error, just tweak a bit myself.
Try add this on APP/Console/kernel.php

```
protected $commands = [
    //Commands\Inspire::class,
    // Register Baum nestedset command
    Commands\BaumCommand::class,
    Commands\InstallCommand::class
];
```

and create two files and copy BaumCommand.php and InstallCommand in /vendor/baum/baum/src/Baum/console.
then change a namespace at the top.

```
namespace Baum\Commands;
```

to

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;
```